# Advice on how to add a Variable File path to my download script

Tags: php

I am Working on a download php script but my file path is variable Can i use get() to get the file path of the file. OR can i do something else. 
Thank You For Your Support.

PHP Script -

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
$filename = $_GET['file'];
} else {
$filename = NULL;
}
$err = '<p>Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.</p>';

if (!$filename) {
// if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
echo $err;
} else {
// path
$path = './'.$filename;
// check that file exists and is readable
if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
    // get the file size and send the http headers
    $size = filesize($path);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    // open the file in binary read-only mode
    // display the error message if file can't be opened
    $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
    if ($file) {
        // stream the file and exit the script when complete
        fpassthru($file);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
} else {
    echo $err;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `$_GET` to get the file name and it looks like you already do. So what is the question/problem?

Comment: is it safe to do so? I myself Don't want to do so cause it reveals to complete path of the file to the end user which is what i am trying to prevent. So is there any other safe way to do it,

Comment: @Progman the url ends up like this               somesite.com/download.php?download_file=test.doc&path=/t1/a/test2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that you shouldn't allow downloading any file the user wants, this is a huge security risk. There are several ways how to avoid this, depending on what you have available.

- Store in a database (or file or PHP script) all possible download paths. In the URL you use an identifier to specify the file to download, like the ID of the database row. When the user opens the URL `http://www.example.com/download.php?id=42` the PHP script fill lookup the download entry in the database by the given id and use the path saved in the database. This way you have a whitelist of all possible download files.
- Use [`realpath()`](http://www.php.net/realpath) to check the file the user wants to download. Then check if the path is inside the allowed download directories. This way you prevent access of sensitive files outside the specified download directories.